# How to keep entered values in PHP so users don't have to type them again after hitting the submit button?

Tags: php

Let's say we have a form with several input fields such as first name, last name, phone number, the message, and all of these have validation. We enter all but the first name because we forgot. We hit submit to send the data, but we're returned with an error because we forgot to enter our first name. All information entered is still present so we don't have to type it again.

How can I go on about doing this? The code below was taken [from this website](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/).

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'myemail@mail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: Echo them in the form in html, <?=isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "" ?>

Comment: @Robin: you're probably safe with `post` operations, but nevertheless it would be a good idea to get into the habit of rendering that with `htmlspecialchars()`. Otherwise it is only a small step towards beginners rendering `get` variables unescaped, and getting into all sorts of XSS trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to store information and display value in form like

> PHP

```
<?php

  session_start();

   $form_name = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '';
   $form_email= isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '';
   $form_message= isset($_SESSION['message']) ? $_SESSION['message'] : '';
   $form_human = isset($_SESSION['human ']) ? $_SESSION['human'] : '';

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        //store information into session

        $_SESSION["name"]=$_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION["email"]=$_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION["message"]=$_POST['message'];
        $_SESSION["human"]=intval($_POST['human']);

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'myemail@mail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    .....
     ....
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';

      //remove information from session
      unset($_SESSION["name"]);
      unset($_SESSION["email"]);
      unset($_SESSION["message"]);
      unset($_SESSION["human "]);

    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
```

> HTML

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $form_name; ?>" name="name">
-----
-----
```

Comment: I would guess this code could be used as a spam proxy - no carriage return detection in most of the mail fields, and so extra `To` or `Bcc` headers could be added easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can echo the contents in your html form

Like,

```
   <input type="text" name="name1” value="<?=(isset($_POST['name1']) ? $_POST['name1'] : "") ?>
```

Comment: Hi Robin, this doesn't seem to work when I implement this into my html form.
value="<?=(isset($_POST['name1']) ? $_POST['name1'] : "") ?>

I notice the "php" is missing right after the question mark. Is this intentional? Also is there a reason why POST is listed twice here? Thanks!

Comment: Yes.. php was intentionally missed. Post is listed twice to check if post exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>">
```